# Is there a polynomial with rational coefficients $P(x)$ such that $\frac {P(n+1)}{P(n)}\in\mathbb{N}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$?

Tags: polynomials

Does there exist a polynomial with rational coefficients $P(x)$  with the property $\frac {P(n+1)}{P(n)} \in \mathbb{N}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$? If so how can I construct such a polynomial?

Comment: Presumably you want the polynomial to be non-constant?

Comment: Yeah it should be of at least first order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every polynomial $P(x)$, one has
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{P(x+1)}{P(x)}=1,$$
and so if a polynomial satisfies the desired property, one must have $P(n+1)=P(n)$ for all $n$ large enough, hence constant polynomials $P(x)=c$ are the only polynomials with that property.

Comment: Nice!  Also worth noting that it suffices, by cancelling the common factor, to assume that $P(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, from which it is easier to see that $P(n+1)=P(n)$ for $n$ large.

Answer (score 1):

Assume, for sake of contradiction, that $P(x)=\sum_{i=0}^d a_i x^i$ is such a polynomial.  Assume that $d \geq 1$ and that the $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$ have no common factor.

Note that $$\frac{P(3)}{P(1)} = \frac{P(3)}{P(2)}\cdot\frac{P(2)}{P(1)} \in \mathbb{N},$$ and similarly $\frac{P(n)}{P(1)} \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $n$.

Now take $n=\sum_{i=0}^d a_i=P(1)$.  Then we have $\sum_{i=0}^d a_i \mid a_0,$ a contradiction.

Comment: Can you explain why $\sum_{i=0}^d a_i \mid a_0$?

Comment: @Virtuoz With $n=P(1) \mid P(n)$, we see that $n$ must divide the constant term.  Now take $n=\sum_{i=0}^d a_i$.

Comment: thanks, got it :) Your idea works only for $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$, right? Otherwise, I cannot see any contradiction.